# Why the formula $t=\frac{2 u \sin(x)}{g}$ doesn't work for $x=0$, for example, when the projectile is launched horizontally off a cliff?

Tags: kinematics, projectile

Why doesn't the formula $t=\frac{2u \sin(x)}{g}$ work for $x=0$, in projectile motion, for example, when the projectile is launched horizontally off a cliff?

Where $u$ is initial velocity, $x$ is the projectile's angle with the horizontal when initially launched. Therefore, $u \sin(x)$ is the vertical component of the initial velocity.

(For how I concluded that this formula doesn't work is-
when the projectile is horizontally launched, $x=0$
therefore, $t$ boils down to $0$
but it isn't possible that $t=0$ after some time when the projectile reaches the ground.)

Comment: Welcome! Please go through this tutorial how to use MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3):

That's because, that formula is specific to a particular problem where you launch a projectile from ground with an angle say $\alpha$. Then the total time of flight is

$$
T = \frac{2u\sin(\alpha)}{g}
$$

when $\alpha = 0$, which is equivalent of pushing the projectile on ground and it eventually stops the next moment. That's why T = 0 when $\alpha = 0$.

Comment: Why that formula is specific to a particular problem? and how can I know that given a problem, that whether it's that particular problem?

Comment: I got my answer so thought of sharing too- this formula is only applicable for same heights, i.e. y should be same for landing and taking off, reason: because the way the formula is derived, i.e., delta y=0 in the derivation.

Comment: @IshikaWalia Absolutely, That's what I wrote in the first line of my answer.

Comment: But you didn't wrote that it will land too at the same height from the ground in that specific case, it's ok, be sure to write completely from next time(everyone does mistakes, doing a mistake is not bad, but we should learn from them in order to do right things next time), thank you